# Is there a way to get the index of an array struct in its function without parameters?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct

As the title says and without any additional parameters in **Request()** while keeping it clean. Below is an example:

```
struct CPerson
{
    void Request();
}

void CPerson::Request()
{
    // get index

    /* EXAMPLES
    serverinfo* info;
    server.GetInfo(&info, index);
    
    cout << info.username << "\n";
    */
}
```

```
CPerson person[64];

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        person[i].Request(); // i = current index

    return 0;
}
```

edit: fixed title

Comment: `this - person`? Looks like an ugly hack though.

Comment: Are you trying to find out `this`'s position within `person` from within `CPerson::Request()`?

Comment: Probably if "my own index" is something a `CPerson` should know, then it should have a member storing that information.

Comment: @aschepler Sounds like a difficult invariant to maintain, considering move or copy construction.

Comment: why do you need that? `i` is the index. What do you want to happen when you do eg `person[42] = person[0];` ?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I would not attempt to automatically maintain it. Depending on wanted semantics, a copy/move could either force it to a sentinel "no index" value, or keep the index, counting on calling code to reason with "was copied from object with index" if that matters.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux but that's the only way that makes sense. Having an object figuring out it's position inside an array is a messed up design and it doesn't make any sense when you create an object of that class that's not inside an array. OPs problem (if that's the problem he has, because it's not clear to me) is a problem outside of that class and not even remotely related to that class at all.

Comment: @StefanRiedel I'm not suggesting that there is a good solution, my intention was to indicate that the addressed comment seems to imply a simple solution, but that solution needs constraints or extra steps to be safe and practical.

Comment: @report Is there any other reason to keep `Request` no arguments besides so-called "clean"? I do
You can use a static member to keep the index since the elements in the array are constructed in order.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "index of a function". It *looks like* you mean the index in the *array* `person`, where the `this` object is stored. But - from the perspective of `void CPerson::Request()`, there is *absolutely no reason* that the array `CPerson person[64];` has any special significance, and no reason why `*this` should necessarily be in that array, or **any** array. It's also not clear *why* you want to do this. Why should the code of `CPerson::Request()` care about the array index? Why should it *know* that there is such an array?

Comment: Added and commented out  an example for what I would use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case, as long as you can guarantee that `CPerson` is only ever stored in this array, you can use `std::distance()` to get the index, since `this` happens to be a valid iterator into the array.

It's effectively the same thing as just doing `this - person`, but standard library implementations can (and often do) have additional safety nets in debug builds at no performance cost for release builds.

Even with that additional safety, manual error checking to validate the assumption that `this` is part of `person` is still a good idea. For this, you'll want to use `std::less` (as opposed to the relational operators), as it's guaranteed to be globally valid even for pointers that are not inside the array.

```cpp
// C++11 and up.

#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>

struct CPerson
{
    void Request();
};

CPerson person[64];

void CPerson::Request()
{
    // possibly an assert() instead...
    if(std::less<CPerson*>{}(this, std::begin(person)) || 
      !std::less<CPerson*>{}(this, std::end(person))) {
      throw std::out_of_range("not part of person");
    }

    std::size_t index = std::distance(std::begin(person), this); 
}
```

In C++20, you can be cleanly more generic about it, which will let `person` be any contiguous range, like `std::vector` for example:

```cpp
// C++20 and up.

#include <ranges>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

struct CPerson
{
    std::size_t Index() const;
    void Request();
};

CPerson person[64];

// Or possibly
// std::vector<CPerson> person;

std::size_t CPerson::Index() const
{
    static_assert(std::ranges::contiguous_range<decltype(person)>);

    const CPerson* person_b = std::to_address(std::ranges::begin(person));
    const CPerson* person_e = std::to_address(std::ranges::end(person));

    if(std::less{}(this, person_b) || 
      !std::less{}(this, person_e)) {
      throw std::out_of_range("not part of person");
    }

    return std::distance(person_b, this); 
}

void CPerson::Request() {
  auto i = Index();
}
```

Comment: This could be safer if `CPerson` has private constructors and destructor and manages the array itself as a private static member, to make sure objects outside the array will never exist.

Comment: when `this` and `std::begin(person)` are not pointers into the same array the comparison via `>=` can return either `true` or `false`,afaik it doesnt even have to be consistent between `>=` and `<`. Better use `std::less` to compare them